# Dynamic SVG with keyframes - Safari problems

Tags: jquery, css, svg, css-animations

I have managed to approximately simulate my problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pndn3nja/8/).

```
.bigbox {
  width: 50%;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.graphicsContent {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 144px;
  width: 100%;
}

svg {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.circle_animation {
  /*stroke-dasharray: 351.68;*/
}

.t1 .circle_animation {
  -webkit-animation: t1 1s ease-out reverse forwards;
  -moz-animation: t1 1s ease-out reverse forwards;
  animation: t1 1s ease-out reverse forwards;
}
```

I receive dynamic percentage values from a server every x seconds. For the purpose of the demonstration only I have created a random generator with values between 0 and 100 that outputs a number every 10 seconds.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*someRandom();*/

  setInterval(function() {
    someRandom();
  }, 10000);
});

function someRandom() {
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  $('.graphicsContent').text(number + "%");

  var offsetB1 = (number * 351.68) / 100;

  $(".circle_animation").css("stroke-dasharray", offsetB1 + ", 351.68");

  $.keyframe.define({
    name: 't1',
    '0%': {
      'stroke-dasharray': offsetB1 + ', 351.68'
    },
    '100%': {
      'stroke-dasharray': '0, 351.68'
    }
  });

  $(".t1").playKeyframe({ name: 't1' });
}
```

The animation should react to each change. I have included jQuery's keyframes plugin to allow this dynamic creation. Whereas it works flawlessly in Chrome and Firefox, the whole behaviour doesn't seem to work for Safari, hence it will be problematic for Apple users. IE is a common troublemaker, I know very well that CSS3 animations are not supported, but a general cross-browser solution would do the job.

Any help and suggestions (possibly for an alternative plugin as well) are welcome!